# lowercase "a" not working in gnome-terminal but works in xterm?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I'm hesitant to even post this question as I'm sure it must be something simple but looking around I can't see how gnome-terminal would remap keys where xterm and a "real" terminal (ctrl+atl+F1) would not (they all load bashrc etc.) I also checked to see if the symptoms were present with other shells (ksh) and that doesn't change anything.

"a" works fine in other applications and also I ran showkey --scancodes and 'a' actually returns "0x1e 0x9e" which I think is "a down" "a up" so all seems well with the keyboard itself.

At this point I don't know what's causing gnome terminal to interpret "a" any differently than other applications. Does it have a key map of its own?

Update:

Raphael - font: Checked on the font used, it's not customized so I'm using whatever the terminal defaults to

Terdon: Hanging my head in shame... It was indeed a shortcut! Considering I hadn't customized anything, is there a way for this to be done w/o actually going through preferences? However curious the source of the problem, it does fix things. Thanks for taking the time to reply!

Comment: Goto Edit > Profile Preferences. There see which is your font and update your answer.

Comment: Did you run `showkeys` in `gnome-terminal` or another terminal emulator? My guess is that you've made `a` a shortcut for something. Go to edit -> preferences -> shortcuts. Is `a` mapped to anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments above by @terdon it's worth checking the terminal's preferences, somehow had 'a' mapped to something else.